# You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource. pnp

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online, pnp-js

We have an portal where an azure AD user will login and will be able to see the data from list on sharepoint.

Trying to achieve this using [PNPJS](https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/) and [Angular MSAL](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/tree/dev/lib/msal-angular)

For the development phase,executed all list operation successfully using
[sp-rest-proxy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sp-rest-proxy) but when same angular project was built and uploaded in azure web app, it gives an error as `"{"error":{"code":"-2147024891, System.UnauthorizedAccessException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource."}}}`"

Response Headers also have error as `X-MSDAVEXT_Error: 917656; Access+denied.+Before+opening+files+in+this+location%2c+you+must+first+browse+to+the+web+site+and+select+the+option+to+login+automatically.`
Now with SP setup variable

```
const SPHeaders: any = {
  "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
  "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose"
 };
 sp.setup({
  sp: {
  baseUrl: "SharePoint siteUrl",
  headers: SPHeaders
  }
 });
```

Note : User successfully logs in and I can active directory user info with the help of graph api.

I even tried passing token which I get after authentication in SP setup like below, but that gives an error as  **reason="Token contains invalid signature.";category="invalid_client"**

```
 sp.setup({
      sp: {
        baseUrl: environment.web,
        headers: {
          "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
          "Authorization": `Bearer ${token}`
        }
      }
    });
```